# What are the security differences between cookies with Domain vs SameSite strict?

Tags: security, cookies, csrf

When we create a cookie we can specify where it's being used by setting the domain attribute.

```
Set-Cookie: Foo=bar; Path=/; Secure; Domain=baz.qux.com;
```

The cookie above will be used along only with requests to the domain `baz.qux.com`.

```
Set-Cookie: Foo=bar; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=strict;
```

The cookie above omits the `domain` attribute, which means the domain where the cookie was *set* will be used (subdomains excluded, exception for IE). It also has the attribute `SameSite=strict`, which means:

> SameSite cookies let servers require that a cookie shouldn't be sent with cross-site (where Site is defined by the registrable domain) requests, which provides some protection against cross-site request forgery attacks (CSRF).

*from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#SameSite_cookies)*

What are the differences in behaviour between these two cookies if both were set on the domain `baz.qux.com`?

How does the `SameSite=strict` attribute protect against CSRF that the other cookie with specified domain does not?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `Domain` attribute broadens the set of hosts that the cookie will be sent to. The `SameSite` attribute restricts the origins from which the cookie may be sent.

So the first cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: Foo=bar; Path=/; Secure; Domain=baz.qux.com;
```

can be sent to `baz.qux.com` or any of its subdomains, regardless of the requests origin (i.e. whether sent from webpage hosted at `baz.qux.com` or `foo.example.com`)

The second cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: Foo=bar; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=strict;
```

can only be sent to `baz.qux.com` (since no domain specified, and ignoring IE exception,) and only when the request originates from the `qux.com` site (i.e it won't be sent for cross-site requests.)

This helps prevent CSRF by preventing random web sites (`hacker.example.com`) from performing authenticated requests to third-parties (`baz.qux.com`) that include session cookies.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, then setting the domain results in the same behavior as setting `SameSite` to `lax`...?

Comment: @Narfanator not really. Having the `Domain` set still allows the cookie to be sent both in the first-party and 3rd-party context (e.g. when requesting a JS or an image from another domain). The `SameSite=Lax`, however, allows cookies in the first-party context only.

Comment: Wait... Domain means the cookie gets sent if the request is coming from OR going to that domain?

Comment: @Narfanator going to that domain

Comment: I like this answer, which I've already upvoted, but I think it would be less confusing to write that the `Domain` attribute _relaxes_ (rather than _restricts_). See my edit.